# insert rows assign values to cells

Tags: excel, vba

> The Following works well for inserting the new rows but I'd like to
>   add values to those new rows in columns A, B, C, and D.  Same values
>   for every newly inserted row. A="SPL" B="CHECK" C= the value of the
>   cell above it. D="Transfer Account" I'd love it that could be
>   integrated into the loop.

```
Range("A4", Range("A4").End(xlDown)).Select
For Each MyCell In Selection
If MyCell.Value <> "" Then
MyCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
End If
Next MyCell
```

Answer (score 2):

As you're inserting rows with content, it's better to work from the bottom to the top:

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim MyCell As Range, rng As Range, x As Long

    Set rng = Range("A4", Range("A4").End(xlDown))

    For x = rng.Count To 1 Step -1
        With rng.Cells(x)
            If .Value <> "" Then
                .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
                .Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 4).Value = Array("a", "b", "c", "d")
            End If
        End With
    Next x
End Sub
```